# Maximising a quadratic expression in 3 variables

Tags: optimization, determinant, quadratics

If $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$

Maximise $(cy-bz)^2 + (az-cx)^2 + (bx-ay)^2$

This can be written as the square of the magnitude of the determinant:

$$
 \begin{vmatrix}
  \widehat{i} & \widehat{j} & \widehat{k} \\
  x & y & z \\
  a & b & c \\
 \end{vmatrix}
$$

which is the cross product of $(x,y,z)$ and $(a,b,c)$ hence the maximum is $a^2+b^2+c^2$

How do we find the maximum of a general expression: $\sum_{i=1}^3(a_{i}x+b_{i}y+c_{i}z)^2$

What about the special case: $c_{3} = b_{2} = a_{1} = 0$

and an even more special case: $p^2(cy-bz)^2 + q^2(az-cx)^2 + r^2(bx-ay)^2$

Comment: Assume that the general expression is $f(x,y,z)$.

Take $\frac{\delta f}{\delta x}= \frac{\delta f}{\delta y} = \frac{\delta f}{\delta z}=0$.

So you get 3 equations in 3 unknowns ($x,y,z$). Solve to get maxima.

Comment: $|d \times v|=|d||v||\sin(\theta)|\leq |d||v|$

Comment: @Eric The post already includes the maximum for the cross-product case. The OP is asking about a more general situation.

Comment: Agreed. That’s confusing - put your actual question at the top and your work beneath it, and don’t put multiple questions in one post.

Comment: You can use $x=\cos u$, $y =\sin u \cos v$, $z = \sin u \sin v$ and then search for maxima of function of 2 variables $u,v$ without additional restriction like $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$